# Making ROC curve using python for multiclassification - 2

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, scikit-learn, roc

Following up from here: [Making ROC curve using python for multiclassification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133718/making-roc-curve-using-python-for-multiclassification#25133926)
My code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
import numpy as np

y_test_bi = label_binarize(y_test, classes=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18, 19,20,21,2,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,3,40,41,42,43,44,45])
y_pred_bi = label_binarize(y_pred, classes=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18, 19,20,21,2,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,3,40,41,42,43,44,45])
# Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(2):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test_bi, y_pred_bi)
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
```

The shape of `y_test_bi` and `y_pred_bi` are both `(300,46)`, because there are 46 classes, and 300 test data points.

The format of both these matrices is that each column represents one class, and consists of either `0`s or `1`s.

But I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\metrics.py:688: UserWarning: No positive samples in y_true, true positive value should be meaningless
  warnings.warn("No positive samples in y_true, "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\app\Documents\Python Scripts\gbc_classifier_test.py", line 153, in <module>
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\metrics.py", line 172, in auc
    x, y = check_arrays(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 233, in check_arrays
    _assert_all_finite(array)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 27, in _assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError("Array contains NaN or infinity.")
ValueError: Array contains NaN or infinity.
runfile('C:/Users/app/Documents/Python Scripts/gentleboost_c_class_jit.py', wdir=r'C:/Users/app/Documents/Python Scripts')
```

Comment: You have to replace `NaN` or drop them as the error suggests

Comment: There are no `NaN`s, in fact I got both matrices by using the `label_binarize` function. As I mentioned above, my matrices consist only of 0s and 1s.

Comment: Difficult to say without test data, I can't run your code as I don't have your data. So printing the contents of fpr[i] and tpr[i] show no invalid values?

Comment: Yes I've checked, I've also used `numpy.isnan()`, and there are none. There are only 0s and 1s.

Comment: Could be a bug perhaps, what version of scikit learn are you running and numpy?

Comment: Scipy version: 0.13.0, Numpy version: 1.7.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58674/discussion-between-edchum-and-user961627).

Comment: You want to upgrade numpy to 1.8.1 at the very least and sklearn (scikit-learn) and try again